# How can I connect to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk through IP and port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to connect to my Python app on Elastic Beanstalk via TCP socket by using IP and port. Where can I get those information? I tried using Elastic IPs in EC2 but I can't connect to it. Do I have to set something to make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Single Instance Environment type then you'll be able to use a IP however if you're using the Load balancing, autoscaling Environment type then you'll need to you CNAMES.

Secondly you'll need to open the port you want to connect to by either manually opening in the **EC2 security groups** or using .ebextensions because by default only certain ports are open.

Log into your machine and telnet to the localhost and the port of your Phyton application, if you connect then; find the IP of your machine, open the port in the EC2 security group assigned to that instance and try the telnet again which will tell you if you port listening or not.